# MATLAB takeing huge 350 mb memory to write one column vector to txt file

Tags: matlab

I have a variable `sndpwr` which have 18000 rows and just one column. When I use `fprintf` it takes 350mb txt file to write. Even `csvwrite` and `dlmwrite` take 200+ mb space.

Can anyone tell me any function or method that will write it in a small text file. I am importing it in another program which is not able to import such large files.

```
fid = fopen('sndpwr.txt','wt');
fprintf(fid,'%0.6f\r\n',sndpwr');
fclose(fid);
```

Thanks!

EDIt: in workspace it is described as 31957476x1 double. Sorry for my previous incorrect data.

Comment: `fid = fopen('sndpwr.txt','wt');`  This compiled with single quotes?  When did C++ become JavaScript?

Comment: My first action would be to double-check that your variable `sndpwr`  is indeed of size `[18000 x 1]`. @PaulMcKenzie, the `C++` tag is not relevant, it should be removed. This is `Matlab` code.

Comment: use `nbw = fprintf(fid,'%0.6f\n',sndpwr);`. You don't need `\r\n` as this gives you an empty line between each value line. You also don't need to transpose (remove the `'` after `sndpwr`). The `nbw` variable will contain the number of byte written to disc by the function `fprintf` (double check that value). If I save `sndpwr = rand(18000,1) ;` into a text file with the code above (with my suggestion), I end up with a file of only 176KB. I strongly suspect that your `sndpwr` variable is not as you think.

Comment: Thanks @Hoki.. Yes i looked it up in wrkspace. that sndpwr variable has huge no of rows. I tried your suggestion but still getting same 304MB txt file.

Comment: On another note, 350 MB is not that big for text editors to read. Don't use notepad, use `notepad++` or any other editor.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way to compress your data without using an actual compression algorithm. You have `3x10^7` numbers, written with six digits after the decimal point, at least one before, and a couple of newline characters. This gives `3x10^7 * 10 = 3x10^8` bytes, as a bare minimum. Since 1MB is approximately `10^6` bytes, you are getting a file on the order or 300MB.

If you were to write the file in binary using the `double` datatype, the file would likely be about 20% smaller since doubles are generally 64-bit (8 byte numbers). If you were to use the `single` datatype, there might be some information lost since `single` can only hold approximately 5 digits of decimal precision, but the file would only be 40% of its current size.

If binary is not an option, you can always split the data into smaller text files.